# Multicollinearity in polynomial regression

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, polynomial

How to deal with multicollinearity in polynomial regression? Suppose I have $x$, $x^2$ and $x^3$ as independent variables in my regression equation. How can I calculate and remove multicollinearity from my model?

Comment: If interpretation of the coefficients is not a huge concern, demeaning $x$ has helped me in practice. doing so essentially removes all correlation between $x$ and $x^2$.  If you further standardize $x$ (by dividing by standard deviation) than your resulting coefficients can be interpreted as change per standard deviation, squared standard deviation, and cubed standard deviation from the mean of $x$ respectively.  If your looking for more flexible curve fitting, splines and kernel regressions have there advantages too...

Answer (score 8):

Don't use polynomial transformations "as such", because they will be collinear, as you note. Instead, transform them into [orthogonal polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials). In R, use the `poly()` command.

Even better, don't use higher order polynomials at all, since they will become unstable at the boundaries of your data space. Instead, use [splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29). In R, look at the `splines` package. For more information, look at Frank Harrell's [*Regression Modeling Strategies*](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/RmS/rmsDescription.pdf).

Comment: From the standpoint of pure prediction, extreme algebraic co-linearities do not hurt.